# Solr query issue with double quotes

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to SOLR, was trying to search data by query but found one behaviour difference in terms of using single quote and double quote in filter query.

So, I have one field whose data type defined is `org.apache.solr.schema.TextField` as I want partial search as well.

Take field name as misc_data which holds Multivalued Data

Sample Data = ["5|abc|xyz","12|abc|xyz","22|abc|xyz"]

Issue is : If I use filter query  as `misc_data:"5"` or filter query `misc_data:"12"`, I don't get any result whereas If I use filter query as `misc_data:"22"`, I get the corresponding row.

So here, If I use double quote in filter query for value lower than 20, I am not getting any data.
If I use single quote like `misc_data:'22'` or , `misc_data:'5'` I am getting data against all three cases.

Schema Details

```
<field name="misc_data" type="text_misc_data" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" default="null"/>   


<fieldType name="text_misc_data" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="dummy.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="dummy.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="dummy.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="dummy.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="dummy.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Can some one pls help me to understand what could be case over here causing this behaviour.

PS : `solr-spec is 8.6.2`

Comment: What is the analysis chain defined for the field? In your sample data, are these three separate values? i.e. is one value `5|abc|xyz`, one `5|abc|xyz``, etc., or is the value the complete string as formatted?

Comment: @MatsLindh : Schema Details Updated in Question. And yes, it's stored as single value i.e ["5|abc|xyz","12|abc|xyz","22|abc|xyz"] - 3 diff values seperated by comma.

Comment: Any reason why you don't store it as a proper multivalued field instead? You can then use `|` as the tokenizer to get the values indexed independently and properly match your queries. Now you're instead depending on the behavior of WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory to match the behavior you're looking for, and which is probably what's making this behave weird.

Comment: Thanks, Let me check on that..if that can help to get rid of this behaviour